# Spacetime effects on human scale objects?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, acceleration, time

For a human standing upright on the earth, gravity would have a different value at the feet than at the head, and gravity influences the flow of time. Does the difference in the flow of time cause any effects?

I was toying with the idea that gravitational acceleration is just nature trying to compensate for time flowing at different speeds with a preference for moving towards slower timeflow.

Highschool level question.

Comment: at the human scale newtonian mechanics is basically the truth. So there really are no noticeable effects from general relativity. Now because gravity pulls down there usually is more blood pooling in the legs/feet than the head when you are standing, but that has nothing to do with the flow of time.

Answer (score 1):

The time dilation depends on the factor $\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$  see for example [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)

From this formula the ratio of the flow of time for two points with a height difference of $h$ is about

$$1+\frac{GMh}{r^2c^2}$$

and using data for the earth and $h=2$, the time difference that would pass over a human lifetime for someone's head and feet is about $3 \times 10^{-7}$ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually now possible to measure the difference in time flow across a millimetre of height.

In [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sciencenews.org/article/atomic-clock-general-relativity-time-warp-millimeter-physics/amp) report by Emily Conover at Science News, she details how:

> physicist Jun Ye of JILA in Boulder, Colo., and colleagues used a clock made up of 100,000 ultracold strontium atoms ... after correcting for non-gravitational effects that could shift the frequency, the clock's frequency changed by about a hundreth of a quadrillionth of a percent over a millimeter, just the amount expected according to General Relativity.

They also add:

> Previously, scientists have measured this frequency shift, known as gravitational redshift, across a height difference of 33 cm.

So this is an improvement by a factor of around 300.

Answer (score 0):

That can be thought the other way around. Suppose a spaceship in the outer space with an acceleration $g$. The crew would feel 'gravity' normally as in the Earth.

But according to relativity, for the ship keeps the same distance between parts, (as it should be to keep its integrity), the 'bottom' portions must have a bigger acceleration than the 'top' parts. Particulary, the people head has a smaller acceleration than the feet for someone stand up. And a clock in the head thicks faster than another in the feet.

Of course the difference in completely negligible for all pratical purposes. But it shows the correlation between time difference and acceleration. Both are linked, but I don't think that one causes the other.